# Facebook Page Calendar Export

Tags: facebook, calendar, facebook-page

Is there any way of exporting upcoming events from a Facebook page into your own calendar?

For example, this page:
https://www.facebook.com/Kato?sk=events has two upcoming events.

If you press the "export" link below the events, it will just export your own Facebook calendar.

I want to export these upcoming events, even though the user has not marked that they will attend them, and nothing but that. I would like it to function the same way as the current Facebook "export" function does.

Is it possible through the developer API or is it do-able in an even easier way?

Comment: This is a programming question. I wanna know how to pull out the data by API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to have the correct permissions to perform this action.
To get all the events created by a person/page, all you have to do is query the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) as follows :
`https://graph.facebook.com/{EVENT_CREATOR_ID}/EVENTS`
In your case the `EVENT_CREATOR_ID` is the `page_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook does not generate ical exports for page and group events.

Here's more info:
http://makeaboldmove.com/tutorials/how-to-sync-facebook-page-events-with-google-calendar/

basically you either do it by yourself with the API following the instructions or use the free http://www.wallflux.com/ service. You can use the service even without registering but there is one drawback. If event description is too long, it is cut off without an expansion option and there is no link to the facebook event. So you need to have your events shorter or at least put most important information in the beginning.